# Sorting date by year and group them by week

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an array of dates from last year and this year. I want to group my data by week number and sort them by year. Week 3 of 2019 is wrong and I don't know why.

```js
const test = [
    '2019-02-02T00:00:00.000Z',
    '2019-01-25T00:00:00.000Z',
    '2019-01-07T23:00:00.000Z',
    '2019-01-16T23:00:00.000Z',
    '2019-01-07T23:00:00.000Z',
    '2019-01-06T23:00:00.000Z',
    '2019-01-09T23:00:00.000Z',
    '2019-01-08T23:00:00.000Z',
    '2019-01-08T23:00:00.000Z',
    '2018-12-19T23:00:00.000Z'
];

const groupedResults = _.groupBy(test, (result) => {
  return moment.utc(result).startOf('isoWeek').format('YYYY-W');
});
console.log(groupedResults);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT** Week 3 should be after week 2 (as in 2,3,4,5), not before

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited, thanks for your edit too.

Comment: *Week 3 should be after week 2*...how does that help?

Comment: An object is an unordered set of properties. If you need order, you should really work with an array.

Comment: @trincot - Not anymore, but of course, *using* the order is *very* rarely the right solution, if ever. :-)

Comment: I know that, but it is I think better to maintain the principle that objects should not be used to have a certain order of properties.

Comment: @trincot - I'd suggest to avoid misunderstandings or promulgating incorrect information, acknowledge that order exists but then suggest not using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Week 3 should be after week 2 (as in 2,3,4,5), not before

Two issues there:

1. You've done nothing to sort the result, and the input isn't in sorted order, so naturally the result isn't sorted.
2. Although object properties do have an order now (as of ES2015), some operations (`Object.keys`, `for-in`) aren't required to respect that order. (And moreover, as Trincot points out, *conceptually* objects don't have an order to their properties even though mechanically they do.) In general, if you want order, use an array, not an object. Alternately, if you want a defined order and key/value pairs, use a `Map`, which maintains its entries in creation order (for all operations on the `Map`).

If you want to stick with an object and rely on ES2015+ property order, your simplest solution is to sort your input before you create your output, so that the properties for the weeks are created in the order you want (because those property names aren't integer indexes, so they'll be listed in the order they're created).

If you switch to an array, then naturally you can easily sort the resulting array however you like.

Comment: I saw that I don't order my array by deleting a lot of dates thanks to you. Irrelevant question then, thanks for your help.